# Wiring a bulb holder to a plug, what cable to use?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I want to wire a bulb holder [like this one](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07V3W13TP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1), to a plug using some flex cable, so i can use it like a lead light / inspection light, move it to different places etc...

So I just want to check that I'm going about this correctly with regards to the wiring. The holders only have a live and neutral connection and no earth, so my plan is to use 2 core 1.5mm2 flex cable (no earth) about 15m long ([like this](https://www.screwfix.com/p/nexans-round-flexible-cable-3182y-2-core-1-5mm-x-25m-white/186fk)) run directly into the plug with a 3A fuse. Is this ok? Or should I be using 3 core anyway and just terminating the earth in the lamp holder?

(I'll be using a 60w led bulb, if that matters...)

Thanks for any advice you can give..

(in the UK btw)

Comment: I would use Sj cord junior service on this side of the pond but your code may differ I would verify with the instructions , there are many different types thermoplastic, rubber are the main types there are hard service where the insulation is thicker but may be two thick for the fixture. Hopefully someone from your side will help out your location would also be helpful. I understand U.K. but more specific could be important.

Comment: "Sold by PEBA STORE and Fulfilled by Amazon."  So more Amazon Marketplace stuff, usually, this is direct-ship from China to the Amazon warehouse, and does an "end run" around EU safety regs.  Totally unsafe, at least until January 31.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: what's the significance of the 31st of jan?

Comment: 60W of LED? that's some light bulb, better stock up on welding glasses, and fire extinguishers. there's no point in an unconnected earth wire, unless you want to upgrade it later to something with touchable metal. A 1A fuse would be a better fit for 60W..

Comment: @dandavis After that Britain won't be subject to EU regs.